# How can I use an Access query which uses Access-VBA-defined functions in Word VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office, ado, ms-word

**State of the question:**

<s>I no longer think it is relevant that I'm referencing Excel or that the query has parameters. I think question boils down to this: How can I use an Access query which uses Access-VBA-defined functions in Word VBA?</s>

What I want to do [is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417139/how-can-i-use-an-access-query-which-uses-access-vba-defined-functions-in-word-vba/2418362#2418362), how can I make an inlined version of the Acos function work with my query, as per [shahkalpesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417139/how-can-i-use-an-access-query-which-uses-access-vba-defined-functions-in-word-vba/2417761#2417761)?

---

I have a function in Access VBA:

```
Public Function Acos(radians As Double) As Double
     Acos = WorksheetFunction.Acos(radians)
End Function
```

`WorksheetFunction` is coming from referencing Excel (which I do simply because it defines the acos function).

I use this function in a query that has three parameters. Then I run this query in Word VBA as follows:

```
Dim command As New ADODB.command
With command
    .ActiveConnection = connection
    .CommandText = "MyQueryName"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
        "Param1", adDouble, adParamInput, , param1Value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
        "Param2", adDouble, adParamInput, , param2Value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
        "Param3", adDouble, adParamInput, , param3Value)
End With

Dim records As New ADODB.Recordset
records.Open command, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

I get an error in Word VBA that the function Acos is not defined.

Ideas?

**UPDATE**

In response to comment: Yes, the query works perfectly in Access.

Also, just a note, this is all Office 2007.

**UPDATE 2**

We are going from Access to Word because the VBA program is already in Word but needs to do some data crunching which it isn't really practical to do in VBA.

Changing to creating an Excel Application object has no effect aside from dramatically slowing down the query.

**UPDATE 3**

I have the reference to Excel in both Word and Access. (If there is a better way to get an acos function, I'm certainly open to it.)

Comment: Are you able to run the Access query (that uses Acos) inside Access without any errors?

Comment: I would have expected Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Acos = xl.WorksheetFunction.Acos(0.1)

Note also that if you feed in the wrong value for radians, you will get an error.

Comment: Also, why are we going from Access to Word?

Comment: You didn't mention it, so I have to ask.  Did you add the Excel DLL to your Word reference library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Excel to get the result of `ACos`, try this

Where X = field which contains value that will be passed to `Acos`

```
SELECT X, IIF(X = 1, 0, Atn(-X / Sqr(-X * X + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1))
FROM myTable;
```

Here is the [page](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread33303.html#), I referred for `ACos` formula.

Try & save the above query.
Access has other functions in it such as `Atn` and `Sqr` which can help you get what is needed for `ACos`. Hence, you will not need to ask Excel to calculate things for you.

Note: You will have to do the error handling for values not supported by `ACos`.
e.g. `=ACOS(1.25)` gives you `#NUM!` (not a number)

In a similar way, if the parameter to the above query is 1.25, it will return an error.
So, be careful and validate the input to make sure that query doesn't crash.

Comment: This works for replacing the Acos function, but it still won't let me run the query from VBA. I will try inlining this, but the X I'm running Acos on is a very complicated expression so it's going to be a tremendous mess.

Comment: Actually, the expression in my call to Acos is so long Access won't let me inline this function...

Comment: Is there a way, you could dump the X value into field Y of an intermediate table & use the field Y as parameter to this expression?

Comment: How do I refer back to a previously calculated field? I tried just putting the field name in the expression and Access asked for the value as if it was a parameter.

Comment: I ended up having to make a temporary column and then calculate the real result, but then it wouldn't let me sort on that without doing what I said before about asking for the calculated field as if it was a query, so I had to make a second query which queries the first query then sorts.... BUT IT WORKS.

Comment: @Daniel: Using `WorksheetFunctions` creates Excel application in the background. The subsequent calls to methods of `WorksheetFunctions` will use that instance. I am not sure why there isn't a COM library which does that for us (i.e using excel formulas without excel). I remember having used some library like that & am unable to recall that. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Per this page:

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/124351-custom-function-vba-access-stored-query-called-asp-net

I don't think what I *want* to do is possible. If anyone can give more information on how to make shahkalpesh's answer work, I'll give credit for the answer there.